# Display second maximum salaried employee details using Joins

Tags: sql-server-2008

Question: I need to display second maximum salaried employee details

Tables:

`Emp_Mstr: eno, Name, Dept,Desig,Branch_No`

`Sal_Mstr:eno,sal`

> select e.eno,e.Name,e.dept,e.desig,s.sal
>   from Emp_Mstr e inner join Sal_Mstr s
>   on e.eno=s.eno
>   where s.sal=(select max(sal) from Sal_Mstr where sal

Comment: Could you elaborate more the tables, or post any failed attempts?

Comment: You should have tried something like Google Search,Your question will get closed if you don't tell others what the efforts you have taken what exactly you want and what you have done so for.Welcome to SO read http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: write your sql query..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this one-

```
Select e.eno,e.Name,e.dept,e.desig,s.sal from Emp_Mstr e  inner join Sal_Mstr s 
ON e.eno=s.eno where s.sal= ( SELECT MAX(sal) FROM  Sal_Mstr
WHERE sal NOT IN (SELECT MAX(sal) FROM  Sal_Mstr));
```

Comment: Thanks NetStarter..

Here we get maximum salary, but i need employee details along with salary

Comment: @user2470855 Updated my answer.Please Tick it if you ind it helpful

Comment: @user2470855 Welcome from next time be specific while asking question and don't forget to show your efforts unless your question will be bombed with downvotes and will be closed.We Run SO like this only.Please accept the answer if helpful.

Comment: Ya sure NetStarter...

Your Answer is very Helpful to me...